# Can't start httpd service due to tampered or incorrect password

Tags: terminal, rhel, openssl, ssl

I am on Linux Redhat OS. I was trying to import certificate using this command

```
keytool -importcert -alias 3dspace ...
```

as can be seen in the image below. But it doesn't allow to as it states that either the keystore was tampered or the password was incorrect.

To make matter worse, now I can't run the service httpd as well even though it was running prior to this problem. What can be the cause and how to solve them?

[image]

Comment: welcome to U&L, please do not post test as image, this hinder the use of search tools.

Comment: I believe you can validate a configuration file with Apache. Have you tried running `apachectl -t <location of http.conf>` or `apachectl configtest <location of http.conf>` I also believe the SSL configuration is in a separate file. Can you `cat` both of the configuration files (omit the comments).